# Repeat ajax call in AngularJS with node express js

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, express

I am starting using AngularJS, and setup a server with nodejs, everything goes great, but when i open chrome developers tools i see that the app make two ajax repeat calls for get the json data  that node/mongo send.
first i think that the template jade was the problem, but after use plain html, works in the same way

[a demo in appfog](http://angularforo.ap01.aws.af.cm/)

any idea?

here is the code in AngularJS

```
angular
.module('foro')
.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when("/",{
            templateUrl : "/partials/questions.html",
            controller: "QuestionsCtrl"
        })
        .when("/questions/:questionId",{
            templateUrl: "/partials/singleQuestion.html",
            controller: "SingleQuestion"
        })


    })
    .controller("QuestionsCtrl", function($scope, $http){

        $http.get("/questions").success(function(data){
            $scope.questions = data;        

        }); 
   })
   .controller("SingleQuestion", function($scope, $http, $routeParams){
      var questionId = $routeParams.questionId;

      $http.get("/question/"+questionId).success(function(data){
          $scope.question = data;
          $scope.votes = data[0].votes;
      });
```

this is how respond in node/express server

```
app.get('/questions', function (req, res) {
  Question.find({}).sort({_id:"descending"}).execFind(function(err,docs){
      if(err) res.json(err)
      res.json(docs)
  });
});

app.get('/question/:questionId', function (req, res) {
  var questionId = req.params.questionId;

  Question.find({_id: questionId},function(err,docs){
      if(err) res.json(err)
      res.json(docs)
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you have `ng-controller="QuestionsCtrl"` in your partial.

The route config already assigns the designated controller to `ng-view` when you load the partial.

```
      $routeProvider
        .when("/",{
            templateUrl : "/partials/questions.html",
            controller: "QuestionsCtrl"
        })
```

This results in the same controller being nested twice.

Remove the ng-controller part from this line `<div ng-controller="QuestionsCtrl">` in `questions.html`

Comment: thanks a lot finishingmove problem solved!